# What am I supposed to see in the "Build History of Hudson" diagram?

Tags: hudson

When clicking on Build History in the Web UI of the Hudson CI, I get a list of builds that happend in the past. Fine.

But above that is a diagram, sort of a timeline that I can drag back and forth. But there is nothing in that timeline!?

What is supposed to be displayed there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer perhaps, but it seems that this feature just isn't working
http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-6439

Comment: It's a perfect answer. After all it is hardly your fault this feature isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Just a touch up note!

Currently Internet Explorer displays this feature as blank...

But using Firefox I can see Dates (scrolling in this frame is enabled)!!! …but Dates only...
These dates start around (maybe a day or two before) the creation of the Job!!

Comment: You can scroll around in that field to see when the builds where performed. Of course you only see builds that are not deleted yet. My standard is max 14 days and between 20 and 200 runs. So not much to see for most of my jobs (20 runs). I can do without that view without missing something.